# What does "opens to" mean in this sentence?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I've come across the expression "opens to" in [an article from the New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/11/03/books/review/malala-yousafzai-magic-pencil-drawing-writing-children.html):

> In the transcendent wordless picture book “Lines,” Suzy Lee (“Wave,” “Shadow”) uses her pencil to draw the reader into layers of her imagination. The book **opens to** a drawing of a blank page, with only a pencil and eraser. From there, we follow a lone, red-capped ice skater who glides on an expanse of white ice, her skates creating a trailing line behind here.

And I found a similar expression [here](http://www.radiotimes.com/news/tv/2017-11-16/amazon-has-launched-three-quirky-female-led-comedy-pilots-heres-our-verdict/):

> ...there are some funny, insightful moments – it **opens to** her describing a dream, in which she gives birth to herself, to her friend...

Does **"opens to"** mean **"opens with"** or **"begins with"** in these two examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer** 
*This may sound very confusing, but I'm finding it hard to put it into words. You could argue that they could be used interchangeably, but I leave that to you.*

---

Roughly, yes.

When you use the usage '***opens to***', in contexts involving books or movies (or even plays), you could literally take the phrase as you read it. A book opens, a play or a movie starts. As you mentioned, *'opens with'* and *'opens to'* implies the same thing - "***to starts with***" or "***begins with***".

However, there are subtle differences between '*opens to*' and '*opens with*'. Let me explain this with a few examples.

> "*The book **opens to** a scenic village in western Europe, the comforting warmth of a mid-summer breeze...*"

Here, '*opens to*', gives the reader a feeling that he/ she is transported from where he/ she was, to the places within in the story.

> "*The movie **opens with** the scream of a little girl, who is nowhere to be seen, but can distinctly be heard, echoing through the hollow corridors of the old school...*"

Here, '*opens with*' illustrates a situation, or an event.

Although very subtle, it may be used differently.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and pointing out the subtlety! Very instructive.